# SQL convert comma separated column into row and save it to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `food` having column `speciality`. And values on rows:

```
Speciality (column name)
......................................

Chinese, south Indian, Mediterranean, American
......................................

South Indian, fast food, shakes, coldrinks, Chinese

......................................
```

And I want out as unique values on separate rows like:

```
South Indian
Chinese
Mediterranean
American
Fast food
Shakes
```

And save it to another table `food2` having column name `speciality2`, I want to save those values into that column.

All the database in SQL server 2008.

Comment: Many answers on the web refer to [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).  It seems that you will need to register to get access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the split function along with XML can help you
try below code

```
Insert Into Food2(Speciality2)
SELECT   Distinct
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([Speciality], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) 
     AS String  
     FROM  food) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```